# Change 'eclipse' command to correct PATH

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, eclipse, paths

Currently I have eclipse installed on "**home/gabriel/Programs/eclipse/eclipse**" and I have already created the eclipse.desktop file with correct parameters and it's working fine, but I can't use the command '*eclipse*' at the terminal to open eclipse, it gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/eclipse: 5: /usr/bin/eclipse: home/gabriel/Programs/eclipse/eclipse: not found
```

How do I change the command 'eclipse' to execute only "**home/gabriel/Programs/eclipse/eclipse**"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is a better way, and hopefully someone will provide that as an answer but here is the easy solution I would use.

**Make a bash alias**

Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc

`alias eclipse='/home/gabriel/Programs/eclipse/eclipse'`

Comment: Ops, this only works for the current instance of terminal if I don't write it to my ~/.bashrc, right? Is there a definitive way (without using ~/.bashrc)

Comment: Not using this method. Why don't you want to use `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I do use, but it won't solve other problems (like showing the correct path on DASH) just overwrite it :P